# Gradient of smooth function vanishes

Tags: lebesgue-integral, smooth-functions

Consider some smooth function with compact support $\phi\in C^1_0(\Omega)$ where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and furthermore some constant vector $c=(c_1,...,c_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$. If I am not mistaken, then the Gauß Theorem should imply that
$$\displaystyle\int_{\Omega}c\cdot D\phi(x) dx = 0$$
holds true, simply because $c$ is independent of $x$. Am I right? I just want to make sure I am not mistaken though. Thanks!

Comment: True (bla bla space filling).

Comment: You even have $\int_{\Omega} \partial_i \phi =0$ for all $i \in \lbrace 1, ..., n \rbrace$.